# Edit the last generated migration in shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, rails-migrations

I like to use Vim (and the shell) to edit my files. When I generate a migration, I often find it cumbersome to try to complete through a datetime like `20121209200054`.

How can I edit the last file in `db/migrate` (the one just generated) easily?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply `ls` the directory and feed that into the `vim` command:

```
vim db/migrate/$(ls db/migrate/ | tail -n 1)
```

You can then make a Bash alias out of that (in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`)

```
alias vim-last-migration='vim db/migrate/$(ls db/migrate/ | tail -n 1)'
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

with vim-rails you can just do `:Emigration`